# Change iPhone language from Chinese to English

Tags: iphone

I bought a second hand iPhone 4, and I cannot create an Apple ID since the language appearing is Chinese. How do I change it to English?

Comment: here is a video how to https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=76&v=1BU4KmXRJqA

Answer (score 4):

设置（Setting) -> 通用（General) -> 语言与地区 (Language and Region) -> iPhone 语言(iPhone Language)  , Choose English.

Answer (score 1):

> Change iPhone language from Chinese to English

I do not know if you can read Chinese so here is a video to help you with the process of changing language.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=76&v=1BU4KmXRJqA

Answer (score 0):

Since the text is not recognizable, you can follow along in the Setting app with the help of this Apple Support article, [Change the language on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204031).

Take the help of icons and count of items in a section in the Settings app to navigate through the Settings app. Specifically, you need to go to General → Language & Region → iPhone Language.

As it's a second hand iPhone, it's also advisable to erase it and set it up afresh. This will also reset the device language back to English.